# How Do I exclude a Magento category from the main menu

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.7

How Do I exclude a Magento category from the main menu  and still maintain it in the side bar. I have tried these two code I got while searching on Google by replacing the default magento to these but its not working

Here is the code

```
 <?php $_menu = "" ?>
  <?php if($_menu): ?>
  <div class="nav-container">
  <ul id="nav">
  <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
  <?php if(stristr('71,70,69', $_category->getId()) === FALSE) : ?> 
  <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
  <?php endif ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>

   <?php // echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
   </div>
  <?php endif  ?>
```

And here is the second piece of code. Also I got this from googling.

```
  <?php $_menu = ''?>
  <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
  <?php $_menu .= $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 <?php if ($_menu): ?>
   <div class="nav-container">
      <ul id="nav">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
       <?php if (!in_array($_category->getId(), array(12,34,56))) : ?> <?php echo $this-     >drawItem($_category) ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <?php endif; */ ?>
```

None of them seem to be working. I am using magento 1. 7.1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a category from the top navigation menu but retain the category in the left side menu. Whether a menu items should be show in the top navigation menu can be controlled in the admin. You have to perform the following steps:

Firstly, create a Boolean category attribute with code 'use_in_navigation' using a data upgrade script:

```
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'use_in_navigation', array(
    'type'          => 'int',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'label'         => 'Use in navigation',
    'required'      => false,
    'note'          => '',
    'user_defined'  => '1',
    'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'default'       => false));

    $entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
    $attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

    $installer->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId,
        $attributeSetId,
        'General Information',
        'use_in_navigation',
        100);

    $installer->endSetup();
```

Secondly, override the "_getHtml" from "Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu" and skip the rendering of any children for which 'use_in_navigation' is false:

```
protected function _getHtml(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass){

....

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if(!$child->getUseInNavigation()){
            continue;
        }

        ....
    }
}
```

Something along these lines should do the trick.

Note: The function names have been taken from Magento CE 1.8. They might differ from Magento CE 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

simply 
1- Navigate to **Catalog->Manage Categories**
2- Select the category that you want to **exclude** from main menu
3- set **Include in Navigation Menu** option to **No** (at the bottom of page)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your theme, you may use either prototype or jQuery to remove particular child of UL tag. For example, if you want to remove second category then you can use such code to remove second LI of navigation UL